# jQuery trigger onclick if radio button selected

Tags: jquery

I have a radio button that I want to trigger an onclick event if checked="checked". I'm new to jQuery but I found some code that seems like it should do the trick... except I guess I don't know enough to edit it properly. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" id="id_of_Checkbox">
<input type="submit" id="id_of_button" onclick="doSomething" value="Submit">

<script type="text/javascript">
  if ($('#id_of_Checkbox').prop('checked', true)){
     (function(event){
     $('#id_of_button').click();
     });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$('#id_of_Checkbox').prop('checked', true)` is used to set the `checked` value, to check whether the checkbox is checked use the selector [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) along with [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
jQuery(function($){
    if ($('#id_of_Checkbox').is(':checked')){
        $('#id_of_button').click();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if ($('#id_of_Checkbox').prop('checked')){
   $('#id_of_button').click();
}
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tdcVQ/